# FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction with lazy iterator as return value

Tags: java, apache-spark

When using Apache Spark with stateful processing, it can group rows with same key using `flatMapGroupsWithState` function

```
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.sql("SELECT ... FROM parquetTable")
                             .groupByKey(..., Encoders.STRING()
                             .flatMapGroupsWithState(new FlatMapFunctionEager(),
                                     OutputMode.Append(),
                                     Encoders.kryo(Session.class),
                                     RowEncoder.apply(PARQUET_SCHEMA),
                                     GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout());
```

Generally, examples or tutorials show a `FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction` with a `List<Row>` created first and iterator to it is returned:

```
private class FlatMapFunctionEager implements FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction<String, Row, Session, Row> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Row> call(String key, Iterator<Row> values, GroupState<Session> state) throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        if (state.exists()) {
            session = state.get();
        } else {
            session = createSession();
            state.update(session);
        }


        // here a list is created and populated with results
        List<Row> result = new LinkedList<>();
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            Row row = values.next();
            result.add(process(row, session));
        }

        // here iterator of the list is returned
        return result.iterator();
    }

    private Row process(Row row, Session session) {
        // do processing and return generated row
    }
}
```

However, this sometimes causes memory problems since Spark can group a lot of Rows for processing.
Is it safe to return a lazy iterator that stores Iterator and GroupState provided by the caller?
Or can Iterator and GroupState change after the call and therefore not safe to use them lazily?

Sample code:

```
public class FlatMapFunctionLazy implements FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction<String, Row, Session, Row> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Row> call(String key, Iterator<Row> values, GroupState<Session> state) throws Exception {
        // here we pass the state and values iterator
        return new LazyIterator(state, values);
    }
}


public class LazyIterator implements Iterator<Row> {
    private final GroupState<Session> state;
    private final Iterator<Row> values;

    public LazyIterator(GroupState<Session> state, Iterator<Row> values) {
        this.state = state;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return values.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Row next() {
        // here we use the provided iterator when our iterators next is called
        Row row = values.next();
        return process(row);
    }

    private Row process(Row row) {
        Session session = null;
        // here we query and update the state (GroupState)
        if (state.exists()) {
            session = state.get();
        } else {
            session = createSession();
            state.update(session);
        }


        return process(row, session);
    }

    private Row process(Row row, Session session) {
        // do processing and return generated row
    }
}
```

Is this kind of usage safe or will be the behaviour undefined?

I tried lazy iterator with some sample input and got correct results however I could not be sure for its correctness since sometimes multi-threaded programs may produce correct results even though some race conditions exist and also documentation is not clear about this area.